# Selection of levels of factors within a factor

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

This is my example:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=as.factor(c(rep("A",20),rep("B",15))),var=as.factor(c(rep("w",5),rep("x",10),rep("y",12),rep("z",8))), obs=runif(35,0,10))
```

What I want to do is, for each 'ID', to be able to select a single 'var', at random and possibly by selecting the 'var' with the most 'obs'. So for example, at random it could give this:

```
   ID  var       obs
6   A   x 3.44405412
7   A   x 1.50957637
8   A   x 8.22009420
9   A   x 7.47094473
10  A   x 8.26098410
11  A   x 9.62919537
12  A   x 0.10393890
13  A   x 0.11298502
14  A   x 4.33822574
15  A   x 4.20109035
28  B   z 1.07697286
29  B   z 8.40864310
30  B   z 7.62563257
31  B   z 0.06885177
32  B   z 4.33959316
33  B   z 7.98303782
34  B   z 8.38335593
35  B   z 4.52110318
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another data.table approach. To begin...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

Then, select the `var` for each `ID`:

```
# var with highest #obs
idvar_selected = df[,.(var = .SD[,.N,by=var][which.max(N)]$var), by=ID]

# or... at random, weighted by #obs
idvar_selected = df[,.(var = sample(var,1)), by=ID]
```

And "join" using the selection:

```
df[idvar_selected, on=c("ID","var")]
```

Comment: For some reason, akrun's code gave made RStudio encounter a fatal error each time I tried to run it on the full df containing my data. Yours does not have this problem and worked perfectly on the full df, so thank you!

Comment: @user2092517 Hm, don't know why that would be, as I don't have much experience with Rstudio. If you keep running into problems like that, you might consider making a reproducible example and asking about it using an Rstudio support channel. You could also ask akrun if he has any ideas by commenting on his answer.

Answer (score 3):

One option using `data.table`.

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  Grouped by 'ID' and 'var', we create a variable 'N' that gives the number of rows (`.N`) for each group.  Then, we group by 'ID' and subset the rows that have the `max` value of 'N' (`.SD[N==max(N)]`).  The 'N' column can be assigned to 'NULL' as it is not needed in the expected output.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,N := .N  , by = .(ID, var)][, .SD[N==max(N)] ,
        by = .(ID)][, N:= NULL][]
#    ID var       obs
# 1:  A   x 9.2044378
# 2:  A   x 2.7973557
# 3:  A   x 7.6382046
# 4:  A   x 8.0163062
# 5:  A   x 2.5472509
# 6:  A   x 6.0488886
# 7:  A   x 3.7073495
# 8:  A   x 6.7169025
# 9:  A   x 6.7298231
#10:  A   x 3.2043056
#11:  B   z 5.9973018
#12:  B   z 6.3014766
#13:  B   z 0.4663503
#14:  B   z 3.1951313
#15:  B   z 2.3874890
#16:  B   z 3.6881753
#17:  B   z 1.4802475
#18:  B   z 9.3776173
```

By assigning a new column, we are changing the original dataset 'df'.  We could remove that column later from the original dataset by

```
df[, N:=NULL]
```

Or a modification of the above code without assigning (`:=`) so that original dataset remains the same.  We concatenate `.SD` i.e. `Subset of Datatable` with `.N` to create the new column 'N', and then subset the rows as before.

```
setDT(df)[, c(list(N=.N), .SD) ,by =.(ID, var)][, 
                     .SD[N==max(N)], by =ID][, N:= NULL][]
```

Or as suggested by @Frank, we can `copy(.SD)` to avoid the original dataset getting changed, then assign the 'N', and do as before.

```
setDT(df)[,copy(.SD)][,N := .N , by = .(ID, var)][,
                          .SD[N==max(N)] ,  by = .(ID)][]
```

---

If we want to select random 'var' within each 'ID', we can use `sample` to select a single 'var' grouped by 'ID', get a logical vector (`var==sample(var, 1)]`) and subset the rows

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[var==sample(var, 1)] , by =ID]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(ID=as.factor(c(rep("A",20),rep("B",15))),
         var=as.factor(c(rep("w",5),rep("x",10),rep("y",12),rep("z",8))), 
         obs=runif(35,0,10))
```

Comment: But all this code does is adding the N column in the original df; isn't there a solution where I could obtain the expected output in one go? It seems I'd have to subset the original df according to N if I use this code. The previous comment was me, I saw you edited your answer and thought you mended the point I just brought up.

Comment: @user2092517 The N column was created to get the index of row numbers and later it was removed.

Comment: If I run this code, all I get is the added column though.

Comment: @user2092517  I posted the output I got.  Here i used `set.seed(24)` to create the `df`

Comment: Yes, I think I was missing some [] at the end of the expression. What about a random selection of a 'var' within an ID? Is that feasible?

Comment: @user2092517  A base R option would be `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) {x1 <- table(x$var); subset(x, var==names(x1)[x1==max(x1)])}))`

Comment: The `[]` was just to print the output.

Comment: @user2092517  I updated with a possible random selection.  I hope that is what you requested.

Comment: Seems like it's working perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Like the OP, I am seeing the `N` column added to `df` when running your code. Not sure if you know a way to remove it in your chain, but you could do so on a separate line.

Comment: @Frank Ok, now I understand.  By assigning, it is changing the original dataset.

Comment: Ok, np. By the way, fancy joins are also an option, like `df[ df[,.(var=sample(var,1)),by=ID], on=c("ID","var")]` I'm guessing this uses binary search instead of the vector scan in your `var==sample(var,1)`, which may be faster.

Comment: @Frank I modified with another version.

Comment: @Frank Could you post that as a separate solution as I am tired of adding documentation with each code :-)

Comment: Sure no problem :) Your new solution could instead use `copy(.SD)` as its first step, like `setDT(df)[,copy(.SD)][,N := .N  , by = .(ID, var)][, .SD[N==max(N)] ,
+         by = .(ID)][]`